# Applescript to combine part of URL and clipboard contents - possible?

Tags: regex, parsing, url, applescript, clipboard

I know very little about Applescript, so I'm wondering if what I want is even possible.  Ideally, what I'd like to do is to be able to have a script that will return the last part of the URL of the active Chrome window, top-most tab, and combine that with the contents of the clipboard.  So something like this:

**URL:** "www.site.com/page/number_I_want"
**Clipboard contents:** "text I want to show"

**Desired result:** "number_I_want - text I want to show"

I'm guessing some regex is going to be needed, but is this even possible?  I'm hoping to make this part of a larger Alfred workflow...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set myUrl to URL of window 1's active tab

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "/"}
set myNumber to text item -1 of myUrl
set text item delimiters to TID

set newString to myNumber & " - " & (the clipboard as text)
```